# Heroku - Multiple Process Types in a single procfile

Tags: heroku, procfile

In heroku, if one has the following on a Heroku dyno's procfile (say hobby tier), does that mean they are charged for two dynos? Or is it running on one Dyno sharing the resources of said dyno?

```
web: node ./bin/www
worker: node ./bin/background.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `web` and `worker` dynos can be scaled separately for a given app. So you are charged per dyno at your currently chosen dyno type.

So if you have one web and one worker defined as you show above, on the hobby tier, that would be $14 monthly ($7 x 2 dynos)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling

Comment: Thank you. For other visitors to this page, I've since confirmed this is in fact the case.